# How to Create Random Letter?

Tags: pgfmath, random-numbers

I am trying to create algebra quizzes which are generated by random numbers and each exercise's variable is a random letter from the alphabet.

I think I can do the random numbers.

Not sure how to do the random letters. Is there a function for this in `pgf`? Or do I have to use `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{\listname}{<EntireAlphabet>}` and `\pgfmathrandomitem`?

Answer (score 10):

Because we are dealing with TeX, who cares about efficiency

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\def\getrandomletter{%
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\mytemp}{1}{26}%
  \foreach\x[count=\xi] in{a,...,z}{\ifnum\xi=\mytemp\x\breakforeach\fi}%
}
\begin{document}
  \foreach\x in{1,...,26}{\getrandomletter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I was being silly not remembering `alphalph` package. It converts numbers into various symbols.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath,alphalph}
\def\getrandomletter{\pgfmathrandominteger{\mytemp}{1}{26}\alphalph{\mytemp}}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in{1,...,26}{\getrandomletter}
\end{document}
```

gives the same output.

---

OK I keep on being silly. `pgffor` already understands letters to convert numbers to letters. So we don't need `alphalph`. I'll drink more coffee.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\def\getrandomletter{\pgfmathrandominteger{\zzz}{1}{26}\csname pgffor@alpha\endcsname{\zzz}}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in{1,...,26}{\getrandomletter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `[count=\xi]` do?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything holds the number of spins of the loop

Comment: And there is `\@alph` from the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Apparently coffee isn't working for me :D  *facepalm*...

Comment: Or `\foreach\i in{1,...,9}{\pgfmathrandominteger{\zzz}{65}{90}\char\zzz\relax}`.

Answer (score 5):

Using only plain TeX macros, you can do this:

```
\input random
\newcount\code
\def\ranx{\setrannum\code{`a}{`z}\char\code}

\ranx \ranx \ranx \ranx \ranx \ranx \ranx \ranx \ranx

\bye
```

Comment: Wow, that seems very simple. What does `\code{'a}{'z}\char\code` do? I imagine the `{'a}{'z}` makes the alphabet the set of objects `\ranx` can be assigned to, but I don't know what the other parts are for.

Answer (score 4):

The following doesn't (at the moment) work with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\randomletter}{}
 {
  \int_to_alph:n { \fp_eval:n { randint(1,26) } }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\randomLetter}{}
 {
  \int_to_Alph:n { \fp_eval:n { randint(1,26) } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\randomletter\ \randomletter\ \randomletter\ \randomletter\ \randomletter

\randomLetter\ \randomLetter\ \randomLetter\ \randomLetter\ \randomLetter

\end{document}
```

[image]